# RX - zip with group by not behaving as expected - possible bug?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the program with the following code as a simplified version of something else that I am trying to do:

```
Subject<int> numbers = new Subject<int>();
Subject<string> strings = new Subject<string>();
var oddsAndEvens = numbers.GroupBy(i => i % 2);

var zipped = oddsAndEvens.Zip(strings, 
    (group, str) => group.Select(
        i => new Tuple<int, string>(i, str)))
        .SelectMany(x => x);
zipped.Subscribe(t => Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", t.Item1, t.Item2));

numbers.OnNext(0);
strings.OnNext("even");
numbers.OnNext(2);

strings.OnNext("odd");
numbers.OnNext(1);
numbers.OnNext(3);

Console.ReadKey();
```

The output from the program is

```
2, even
1, odd
3, odd
```

Whereas I would expect the output to be

```
0, even
2, even
1, odd
3, odd
```

I think that what is happening is that the 0 is being observed and a group is created. Each group cannot output any values until a string is observed (and the two are zipped together), but by the time that the first string is observed the number 0 has already been and gone. If I understand RX correctly the group should not output the number 0 until there is something subscribed to it.

Have I misunderstood something? Is there a way to stop the group from outputting until there is a string observed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. The Rx is behaving as it should.

The Zip operator's result selector is capturing a *group stream* and a string. Note it is not capturing the events of the group stream.

When the result selector runs, the group stream has already sent `0`. The `SelectMany` will subscribe to the group stream after the `0` event has gone.

It's only when the string is the first event sent (put the `OnNext("even")` up a line) that you'll be OK because the group will be subscribed to when it is created, which is *just* before the first event is sent into the group.

The `GroupBy` operator will not remember and replay historic events, and it's source is hot.